# how can i fix ie select width?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-6

I don't have enough space to change its width on click or any stuff like that.
I need the main select to keep its orginal size with wider options.

I'm using jQuery / IE6

10x

Comment: Do you want the dropdownlist to expand to fit the width of the selected item? Or, do you just want to set the width of the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

check out:
http://css-tricks.com/select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/

or

http://blog.stephenrushing.com/index.php/jquery/jqueryselectesizer-a-fix-for-ie-cutting-off-select-dropdowns/

Answer (score -1):

try specifying **width** attribute: `<select width="100px">`

Comment: I think he wants something like 

<select name="foo">
<option style="width:500px;" name="foo" value="bar">FooBar</option>
</select>

but only in javascript or jquery